# How to merge two columns in sql and display it into a separate record

Tags: mysql, database

I have this table

```
Column1|Column2
1       2
3       4
```

I want to merge two columns and make them appear like this

```
 NewColumn
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Comment: Using `CONCAT()` function of mysql

Comment: @AlivetoDie I don't think that's what OP wants. He wants to display the results of both columns in the same column.

Comment: @Jackson Tiu, have you tried any of these answers ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay i tried already, it worked with UNION

Comment: ok, @JacksonTiu, cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use `UNION` :

```
SELECT Column1 FROM table UNION SELECT Column2 FROM table
```

Not sure to understand if that's what you want...

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks! Union is the keyword i need

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to do this using php or some script but not using mysql. 
Still, you can achieve this with mysql like this:

```
SELECT t1.Column1 FROM table as t1
UNION
SELECT t2.Column2 as column1 FROM table as t2 ORDER BY Column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is UNION:

```
SELECT column 1 AS newColumn
FROM...
UNION
SELECT column2 AS newColumn
FROM...
ORDER BY newColumn
```

This of course gets unwieldy if you need to combine multiple columns - ideally avoid having to do it by storing data as raw as possible and aggregating instead.